# Convert hex numbers from proprietary database into decimal

Tags: database, hex

I’m trying to pull numbers out of a proprietary database (Lacerte tax software).
They are all whole numbers, stored in 4 bytes. I have put numbers into the program, and then checked out the file with a hex editor. This has allowed me to see how they are stored.
Here are some examples:
-100 = 00 00 59 C0
-4 = 00 00 10 C0
-3 = 00 00 08 C0
-2 = 00 00 00 C0
-1 = 00 00 F0 BF
0 = 00 00 00 00
1 = 00 00 F0 3F
2 = 00 00 00 40
3 = 00 00 08 40
4 = 00 00 10 40
5 = 00 00 14 40
6 = 00 00 18 40
7 = 00 00 1C 40
8 = 00 00 20 40
9 = 00 00 22 40
10 = 00 00 24 40
100 = 00 00 59 40
1,000,000 = 80 84 2E 41
Does anybody have any idea how to convert these hex numbers from the database into decimals?

Comment: what language are you using to do this?

Comment: I'm currently using VBA to read the file and experiment, but I'll be writing a data extractor in Java. The data shown above is just pulled from a hex editor.